# Repeating values in single-column table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I know this title isn't the best one, but i couldn't formulate a better one.

I have a function similar to **STRING_SPLIT()**, which return a single-column table with one row per split. What i need to do is keep the values from the other columns the same in the new rows.

I have a #TEMP Table with many lines like the following one:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMP([A], [ToSplit], [C], [D]) SELECT '549618', 'AAA, BBB', '1.7', '6'
```

I want to turn that line into two lines, one with `AAA`, the other with `BBB`, with the other values remaining equal.

I tried in the select list:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ufn_split](ToSplit,',')) FROM #TEMP
```

ERROR: *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

Then as a condition (i used IN because it's the only that allow subqueries):

```
SELECT A, ToSplit FROM #TEMP 
WHERE ToSplit IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ufn_split](ToSplit,','))
```

No errors, but it only returns the rows that don't need the split. It would only work with **LIKE**, which is not allowed.

So i tried to put a subquery inside the method to create a single column table with one split value per row, that i would go row by row, use `LIKE %ToSplit% on the #TEMP, but again, subqueries not allowed.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ufn_split]((SELECT ToSplit FROM #TEMP),',')
```

ERROR: *Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

My question is, how can i split the values in ToSplit and keep the other columns values?

Comment: provide sample output using the example row

Comment: Be careful using a splitter. If it has a while loop or a cursor you should consider replacing it with a set based approach. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this .use **CROSS APPLY**

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEMP 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ufn_split](ToSplit,',')
)u
```

Comment: Your answer seems like is going to work for me. Can you just elaborate a little further on WHY it is working? Perhaps edit the question? I will accept it as answer no matter what, but it could be more elucidating.

Comment: Apply operator is used for this purpose only.  You can read more from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx. What it does is it will call the interval subquery for each outside value. We can also provide where clause inside the query. It is infact one of my fav thing in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

that will work on SQL SERVER 2016 and to unlimited values.

```
SELECT
  t.*, LTRIM([value])
FROM #TEMP t
CROSS APPLY string_split([ToSplit], ',')
```

Comment: You query does work. Can you just elaborate a little further on HOW and WHY it works? Seems so simple. How does it know where the `CROSS APPLY` results fit?

Comment: Hello, think of CROSS APPLY as a row-by-row INNER JOIN, but the ON condition becomes a WHERE condition in the subquery. In this case, there is no WHERE it will aplly the result of the split. The string split function will be the second table spliting the column ToSplit. Hope it helps.